# Pow Management IC: Li-Ion 2.8 - 4.2V; Sys Volts: 3.3V

Tags: battery-charging, lithium-ion

I am designing a consumer Li-ion powered system with the following constraints:

1. The system volts has to be 3.3V
2. Li-Ion battery charging range is 2.8 - 4.2V
3. Charging is to be done via a standard USB charger.
4. All aspects of battery charging - charging profile, safety timers, input current programming etc are expected.
5. [Desirable] the battery and system is isolated via switch.

I have been searching for "power management ICs" and "Li-ion battery chargers". So far my results have all yielded a battery charger IC only - on battery backup, system volts follow battery volts. I would want an internal buck-boost regulator to provide regulated 3.3V o/p.

e.g BQ40z60, TPS6502x, TPS6502xx, Max77818, LTC4040 (step up regulator only!)

A boost regulator will not work since system volts need to be @ 3.3V (and not at 5V)

My current solution has a BQ24250 for the battery charging and then a TPS63030 as a buck-boost regulator.

Questions:

1. Are such ICs even available?
2. Please recommend some.

Thanks!

Comment: I have read about good experiences of using MCP73831 from MICROCHIP many times.

Comment: Thanks but thats a battery charger only.